# Meaning of で in みたいな感じで、その土地の有名な酒を「地酒」と言う。

Tags: particle-で

- Full sentence

> 旭川といえば男山、札幌といえば千歳鶴
> **みたいな感じで**、その土地の有名な酒を「地酒」と言う。
> 「地ビール」というのもある。

- For a long time I have been thinking of the usage of で in sentences like these, I thought they were the conjunctive で or the *by means of* で.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, I think で is a particle because the part until で adverbially explains how その土地の有名な酒 is called using examples.

In general, if you can replace で with であり or でして, it's a conjugated copula (だ). For example, で is the te-form of だ in the following sentences (で is interchangeable with であり/でして):

- 彼は「やっぱりね」といった**感じで**、全く驚いた様子がない。
  He is like "I knew it"; he doesn't seem to be surprised at all.
- 梅雨はもう終わっている**感じで**、空には雲ひとつ見えません。
  Looks like the rainy season is over, there's not even a cloud in the sky.

On the other hand, で is a condition/situation/means marker (particle) in the following sentences (で adverbially modifies the following verb):

- 彼は「やっぱりね」といった**感じで**こちらを見た。
  He looked at me as if to say "I knew it".
- 空を飛んでいる**感じで**踊ってみてください。
  Try to dance as if you are flying in the sky.