# で of the copula or で cause particle

Tags: grammar, business-japanese, dictionary

Konnichiwa, I found this sentence in a computer science video:

"分からないことだらけで、ググって解決してそしてコードを書いている"

About the part is it the で of the copula "です" for simply connecting two sentences, or the "で" particle confering a cause meaning like "because everything is unknown, I google and... "

I'm sorry for my lack of understanding of ambiguous situations in japanese but because of being in the journey of learning it I cant allow myself to skip some Grammar rules.

Answer (score 2):

This で is the "te-form of だ", but [a te-form itself can denote a reason/cause](https://www.learn-japanese-adventure.com/te-form-cause-reason.html). This type of で can be translated either as "and" or "so".

> 分からないことだらけで、ググって解決してそしてコードを書いている。
> There are so many things I don't understand, **and/so** I (always) google, figure them out, and write code (after that).

By "cause particle", do you mean で as a case particle that denotes a cause, as in 大雨でイベントが中止になった? However, だらけ is a word that describes a state (existence of a large amount of something), not one specific event, so it can't be the direct cause of your googling.

See also:

- [How can I distinguish the particle で from the て form of です?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/94796/5010)
- [Is the で in というわけで the de-particle or the te-form of だ?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/83727/5010)
- [Meaning of で in みたいな感じで、その土地の有名な酒を「地酒」と言う。](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/87660/5010)

Answer (score 0):

Virtually, both meanings are the same. Let's say you're telling your friend how It is difficult to find a certain book online. Example: "I could not find it online **and then** I went to the library". That is virtually equivalent to "**because** i could not find it online I went to the library". Those meanings are separated just for learning sake. They're both the copula.